# sunspot solr search by multiple terms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot

I am using the sunspot_rails gem, and I am trying to do a search like:

search users where name is Mary or Sally

But I can't figure out how to do the or. If I do something like:

```
search = Users.search do
  fulltext 'Mary Sally'
end
```

or

```
search = Users.search do
  fulltext 'Mary'
  fulltext 'Sally'
end
```

I get no results...but if I do either one, and not both, I get the expected results:

```
search = Users.search do
  fulltext 'Mary' #or fulltext 'Sally'
end
```

will return the single item.

Is this even possible with sunspot?

#### -------Solution-------

```
search = Users.search do
  fulltext 'Mary Sally' do
    minimum_match 1
  end
end
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add `minimum_match 1` to your search block because default setting is to match all words, so searching for `Mary Sally` would return records only with those both names included.